# sendTransaction does not send the transaction (geth)

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions, transaction-propagation

I created a local private test network (using geth) with two nodes which are initiliazed with enough ethers and gas using a custom genesis block. Both have accounts and now I wanted to try sending a transaction from one to another. I tried the command given in this link:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal_sendtransaction

However, the transaction stays in the pending transaction list and never arrives at the other node. As I understand theoretically, normally it shoould be sent to the all nodes in the network, no?

Can anyone tell me what can be wrong here?

See the image below where the sending node (top) and the target node (bottom) are shown:

[image]

In addition, I don't understand how but the second node (the node that suppose to receive the transaction) is apparently mining its balanca value is increasing slowly. The first node however remains the same. PS: I made "miner.start" before on both nodes.

Comment: Are you sure both the nodes are talking to each other? If you stop mining on one and start it on the other, do you see the new blocks in the log of the non-mining node?

Comment: I updated my comment @EdmundEdgar, as you can see they should be talking to each other. I will now check about your second question but how would they create block when in the entire system there is just one transaction?

Comment: They should mine regardless of transactions.

Comment: Can they create blocks without having transactions?

Comment: Yup. Just start one of the nodes mining.

Comment: Actually I started both of them but only one of is mining. Is that normal?

Comment: No, that's weird, unless the other one just hasn't finished getting itself ready yet or the box doesn't have enough RAM or something. You should be able to mine with both of them, stop either one, and still see the blocks getting created on the other.

Comment: OK. Is there a command to check whether the minig is active or not? For example, like net.listening, which returning true or false.

Comment: @ÖnderGürcan to check mining you can use `eth.mining` in the console which returns true or false